# Anchor build ParseIntError

Tags: anchor

After I run anchor build, it seems the program.so build success, but error show like below,

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', lang/syn/src/idl/mod.rs:202:76
```

any idea about this?

anchor build show this error, and cargo build-bpf not anymore.

```
└─[$]> anchor build                                                                                                                                                                                   (instructions)
BPF SDK: /Users/reditable/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.10.30/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v
cargo-build-bpf child: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
warning: profiles for the non root package will be ignored, specify profiles at the workspace root:
package:   /Users/reditable/pool/programs/pool/Cargo.toml
workspace: /Users/reditable/pool/Cargo.toml
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.40s
cargo-build-bpf child: /Users/reditable/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.10.30/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf/dependencies/bpf-tools/llvm/bin/llvm-readelf --dyn-symbols /Users/reditable/pools/target/deploy/pool.so

To deploy this program:
  $ solana program deploy /Users/reditable/pools/target/deploy/pool.so
The program address will default to this keypair (override with --program-id):
  /Users/reditable/pools/target/deploy/pool-keypair.json
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', lang/syn/src/idl/mod.rs:202:76
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Comment: Can you provide the anchor code?

Comment: pretty many instructions. i'm not sure what code cause the problem. Issue https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/1623 says maybe const size arrays used as the instruction data, i checked and not found.

Comment: the error message states exactly where the error occurred.  post that line along with 5-10 lines before and after to the question in a code block

Comment: update anchor-cli to 0.24.2, same to anchor-lang and anchor-spl, program build success. but when generate idl file, this error happens and no relative context show. from the anchor source code lang/syn/src/idl/mod.rs:204, it means an idl type start with '[' but not end with ']' then run to function array_from_str, this pattern should not be in the code because the program build succ already.

Answer (score 0):

```
pub struct A{ 
    pub field: [B: B::LEN] 
} 

pub struct B{ 
   pub field:u64; 
} 
impl A{ pub LEN:usize = 8; }
```

if an IdlType is const size array, like [Type: const_size_length]
the size_length part cannot write like Type::LEN, anchor not work with it when parse the code to generate the idl file.

replace [B; B::LEN]  to [B; length]

Comment: this answer needs elaborated.  it is not clear how it is associated with the question